# IText - text disappears from PDF

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm using IText (version 7.1.10) to generate a PDF. Some texts disappears from the PDF. I have tried to debug but can't find where it disappears. I post the question here to see if anybody has encountered the same problem. Is this a known bug in IText?

I have entered the texts below in the same field.
The following string disappears from the PDF:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

The following string is displayed in the PDF:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

These strings are written to a `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text` object inside a `com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph` object.

Comment: Sorry, my rep doesn't allow me to comment but I want to inform you that you need to use the tag itext7 for versions after 7.0

Comment: Please provide [example code](http://sscce.org/) to reproduce the issue.